# NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest data parsing crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser, nsurl

I am using sendSynchronousRequest and receiving data from a web server but the app is crashing while I am trying to parse the received data?

```
NSError *error;  
NSURLResponse *response;  
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error];  
NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   
NSLog(@"data received from url: %@", data); 
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: data];   
[xmlParser setDelegate: self];   
[xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];   
[xmlParser parse];   
[xmlParser release];
```

But after `[xmlParser parse];` the app crashes. I am getting the following:

```
2011-03-01 09:36:31.735 MasterApp[228:207] -[NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f6b000  
2011-03-01 09:36:31.738 MasterApp[228:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f6b000'  
*** Call stack at first throw:  
(  
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0252eb99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185  
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0267e40e objc_exception_throw + 47  
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x025306ab -[NSObject(NSObject)   doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187  
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x024a02b6 ___forwarding___ + 966  
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0249fe72 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50  
    5   Foundation                          0x00114afc -[NSXMLParser parse] + 147  
    6   MasterApp                           0x0000c731 -[identifierList getUrl] + 994  
    7   MasterApp                           0x0000c306 -[identifierList   actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:] + 56  
    8   UIKit                               0x0077047d -[UIActionSheet(Private)   _buttonClicked:] + 258  
    9   UIKit                               0x002dc7f8 -[UIApplication   sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119  
    10  UIKit                               0x00367de0 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67  
    11  UIKit                               0x0036a262 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527  
    12  UIKit                               0x00368e0f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458   
    13  UIKit                               0x003003d0 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567  
    14  UIKit                               0x002e1cb4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447  
    15  UIKit                               0x002e69bf _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7672  
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x02d8a822 PurpleEventCallback + 1550  
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0250fff4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52  
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x02470807 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215  
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0246da93 __CFRunLoopRun + 979  
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0246d350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208  
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0246d271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97  
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x02d8900c GSEventRunModal + 217  
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x02d890d1 GSEventRun + 115  
    24  UIKit                               0x002eaaf2 UIApplicationMain + 1160  
    25  MasterApp                           0x00001dbc main + 102  
    26  MasterApp                           0x00001d4d start + 53  
)  
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'  
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the console output from the crash?

Comment: i add the crash report in my question i hope u know something about it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the parser based on the format of the data you recieve.  To get started, Look at the [NSXMLParser documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the [NSXMLParserDelegate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).  From those pages you can find helpful sample code, [SeismicXML](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007323) and [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394).

Comment: thank u for reply, i am using this NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"data received from url: %@", data);
 
 xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: data];
 [xmlParser setDelegate: self];
 [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
 [xmlParser parse];
 [xmlParser release];

Comment: also implement ,-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser 
didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName
 attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict   ,  -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
 and -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName  but some how my app is crashing after [xmlParser parse]

Comment: This sounds like a different question than the one you originally asked.  Post a new question with code and the crash log. Or, if your question *is* in regard to -parse crashing your code, edit your original question to reflect this.